# Как настроить закрытие всех уровней при закрытии меню через кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код, по нажатию на кнопку раскрывается первый уровень, и реализовано многоуровневое меню так же по клику, при этом при переключении по пунктам внутри меню второй и третий уровень скрываются, но не получается настроить при переключении по кнопке, что бы все уровни тоже скрывались. Подскажите пожалуйста решение.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.--clickable>span, .button').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass('--active')) { //Если подменю уже открыто,
            $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //закрываем его
            return false; //Прерываем дальнейшее выполнение функции
        }
        let menu_second = $(this).closest('.menu-first, .menu-second').find('ul.--active'); //Ищем все открытые подменю текущего уровня через общего родителя по классу .--active
        $(menu_second).each(function (e) { //Пробегаемся по получившемуся набору объектов циклом
            $(this).toggleClass('--active'); //Удаляем у каждого объекта класс .--active, тем самым закрывая ВСЕ подменю текущего уровня
        });
        $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //И открываем подменю, которое нам необходимо
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
    display: none;
}

.--active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Open</button>
    
    <ul class="menu-first">
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 1</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 2</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
    
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
    
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
    
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 3</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link"><span href="">Пункт 4</span></li>
    </ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Присвойте родительскому уровню класс, и через $(this).parents('.classname') делайте с ним что хотите

Comment: Извините, не совсем доходит, можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы вынес обработчик для кнопки отдельно:

- Объявляем состояние для этой кнопки и смотрим на него
- Если надо всё закрыть, то убираем у всех класс `--active`
- Если нет, то добавляем класс `--active` только первому уровню меню

```js
$(function () {
    let closeAll = false;
    
    $('.button').click(() => {
      if (closeAll) $('.menu-first, .menu-first .--active').removeClass('--active');
      else  $('.menu-first').addClass('--active');
      
      closeAll = !closeAll;
    })
    
    $('.--clickable>span').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).next('ul').hasClass('--active')) { //Если подменю уже открыто,
            $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //закрываем его
            return false; //Прерываем дальнейшее выполнение функции
        }
        let menu_second = $(this).closest('.menu-first, .menu-second').find('ul.--active'); //Ищем все открытые подменю текущего уровня через общего родителя по классу .--active
        $(menu_second).each(function (e) { //Пробегаемся по получившемуся набору объектов циклом
            $(this).toggleClass('--active'); //Удаляем у каждого объекта класс .--active, тем самым закрывая ВСЕ подменю текущего уровня
        });
        $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('--active'); //И открываем подменю, которое нам необходимо
    });
});
```

```css
ul{
    display: none;
}

.--active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Open</button>
    
    <ul class="menu-first">
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 1</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 2</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
    
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
    
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
    
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
    
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link --clickable"><span href="">Пункт 3</span>
            <ul class="menu-second">
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 1</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 2</span></li>
                <li class="menu-second__link --clickable"><span href="">Ссылка 3</span>
            
                    <ul class="menu-third">
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 1</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 2</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 3</span></li>
                        <li class="menu-third__link"><span href="">Товар 4</span></li>
                    </ul>
            
                </li>
                <li class="menu-second__link"><span href="">Ссылка 4</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-first__link"><span href="">Пункт 4</span></li>
    </ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```